# Kotlin - "run" for static Java methods

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, static-methods

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*
...
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName())
UIManager.put("ToolTip.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
...
```

I want to get rid of all `UIManager.` qualifiers, like this:

```
UIManager.run {
    setLookAndFeel(getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName())
    put("ToolTip.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
    put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
    ...
}
```

Of course, this code doesn't compile. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: `import javax.swing.UIManager.*`

Comment: I don't want to pollute namespace in other methods.

Comment: I don't see other options without making wrappers. If you don't like the generic name `put` you can make a utility method with another name and call that method. Or make an `object` that wraps every call to UIManager and then call `run` on that object.

Answer (score -1):

you can use '**with**' keyword to achieve that. This is one of the scoping functions in Kotlin.

```
with(UIManager)
{
    setLookAndFeel(getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName())
    put("ToolTip.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
    put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())
    ...
}
```

Ultimately you are expecting some sort of scoping function.This article gives detailed explanation about usecase for each scoping function in Kotlin.  https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84

Comment: your code formatting doesn't match Java/Kotlin conventions https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#formatting

Comment: @Eugene I don not exactly get what you are referring to.

Comment: `For curly braces, put the opening brace in the end of the line where the construct begins, and the closing brace on a separate line aligned horizontally with the opening construct.`

Comment: `Classifier 'UIManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here`.

Comment: @dyukha Yes Thats an issue. Didn't try that with java static. Looking into it. Will update if I can get around that.